# compressing raw data returned by Android AudioRecord.read(byte[], int, int)

Tags: java, android, compression

I am trying to read the audio data using MIC, and I am able to successfully read and save it to a file (wav format) returned by the AudioRecord class. 
Now the real problem is that the file I am creating is too big. say Audio with duration of 5 minutes is taking upto 25MB. 
Can anyone suggest me how to reduce the size. I am open to other file formats as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WAV is expensive. Try MP3. See the code - https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid

Mp3 Encoder: http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.
http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html

I am planning to use this, do you have any experience using it?

Comment: @Algotrek I used it for a Java project (Not Android) for a client a year or so ago. Was great. Give it a try and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Android's [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html). It is only supported on API 18+